# Regex to find words outside of comments and strings

Tags: regex

I want to make a script which capitalizes the keywords of my source code in Fortran 90, for which I thought about using regular expressions and `sed` (this might have been my first mistake :P). I have not managed, though, to get a match which discards words on comments (in my code, everything after `!`) and in strings (everything between single `'...'` or double quotes `"..."`).

The idea is to have a list with all the keywords of Fortran (if, end if, subroutine, abs, allocate...) and use sed with this regex. Please tell me how one could do this, and also if this approach is correct or there are better ways to accomplish what I want. It has to be possible, because somehow the editors correctly highlight this words. Man, if I could tell Emacs "capitalize the blue words please!" :)

Comment: Just FYI, you probably can tell Emacs to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/3414783

this command should capitalize keywords

Caveat: when keywords are not written the way, Emacs expects, fontification will be lost.

Comment: 404 now, sigh. This indicates we should not rely on external links on SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

there are certainly better approaches but I can't tell one at the moment

so with regex you should go these steps:

1. remove comments and strings; store them anywhere
2. search for keyword and do whichever highlighting you want
3. reset the removed strings and comments

for resetting you can probably replace them with the index of an array where you store them

if your strings don't go over several lines you can go these steps line per line

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about sed, but with Perl you could use something like:

```
perl -p -E 's/(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|!.*)|\b(if|end|subroutine|abs|allocate)\b/$1\U$2/gi' file
```

(Adjust quote/comment expressions as needed.)

Comment: This is nice, but I didn't get it to fully work. First, maybe I have an old perl, but the `-E` option doesn't work; I tried `-e` instead. And the condition for single quotes doesn't work, gives me an error (unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'). If I erase it, it works quite well :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally a friend got a solution for me, not using regexps but python. I share it here in case somebody else faces this problem. Here's the python code; it takes two arguments: the input and the output files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

if (len(sys.argv)<3):
  print "Try with two arguments."
  sys.exit()

FILEIN  = sys.argv[1]
FILEOUT = sys.argv[2]

substitutions = {                                    \
            "call":"CALL"                           ,\
            "parameter":"PARAMETER"                 ,\
            "allocatable":"ALLOCATABLE"             ,\
            "dimension":"DIMENSION"                 ,\
            "integer":"INTEGER"                     ,\
            "logical":"LOGICAL"                     ,\
            "double precision":"DOUBLE PRECISION"    \
            }

patterns = []
for s in substitutions:
  patterns.append(["(^[^!]*)\\b%s\\b"%s,"\\1%s"%substitutions[s]])
  patterns.append(['("[^"]*)\\b%s\\b([^"]*")'%substitutions[s],"\\1%s\\2"%s])
  patterns.append(["('[^']*)\\b%s\\b([^']*')"%substitutions[s],"\\1%s\\2"%s])
  patterns.append(["(\([^\)]*)\\b%s\\b([^\)]*\))"%substitutions[s],"\\1%s\\2"%s])

retList = []
f = open(FILEIN,"r")
for line in f:
  for p in patterns:
    prevLine=""
    nextLine="1"
    while (prevLine!=nextLine):
      nextLine = re.sub(p[0],p[1],line)
      prevLine = line
      line = nextLine
  retList.append(line)
f.close()

f = open(FILEOUT,"w")
f.write(''.join(retList))
f.close()
```